# Kubernetes Cert-Manager Expired Certificates

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

I inherited a GKE Kubernetes environment and have been trying to figure this out for days but unfortunately just don't know what to try next.

The cluster is setup to use cert-manager (installed via helm) to apply Let's Encrypt certificates to the cluster. For some reason, this has worked perfectly for over two years but starting on 4/16 I started seeing SSL warnings in browsers for all notes on the cluster.

When I run `kubectl describe certificates site-cloud-tls` the certificate seems to have renewed but is not being applied to the ingress traffic.

```
Name:         site-cloud-tls
Namespace:    cs
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-06-02T09:55:05Z
  Generation:          34
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  cs-nginx
    UID:                   7f312326-851c-11e9-8bf0-4201ac10000c
  Resource Version:        541365011
  UID:                     7f36cc40-851c-11e9-8bf0-4201ac10000c
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    site.cloud (changed name but is correct)
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-dns
  Secret Name:  site-cloud-tls
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-04-24T05:26:13Z
    Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Reason:                Ready
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2022-06-15T17:01:48Z
Events:                    <none>
```

```
kubectl describe ingress
Name:             cs-nginx
Namespace:        cs
Address:          192.168.1.32
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.16.3.12:8080)
TLS:
  site-cloud-tls terminates site.cloud (changed naming but seems correct)
Rules:
  Host                       Path  Backends
  ----                       ----  --------
  site.cloud   
                             /   site:8080 (10.10.10.10:8080)

Annotations:                 certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-dns
                             kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: true
                             nginx.org/websocket-services: datahub
Events:                      <none>
```

We do have a staging environment which was also affected. I have tried re-installing cert-manager, re-installing nginx-ingress but unfortunately haven't been able to get things back up and running (likely due to a configuration error I've made).

After 3 days, I don't know which way is up and don't know Kubernetes well enough to know what to try next. Any guidance? Can I provide any additional info that might help?

Thank you!

Comment: was the answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are referring to a `cluster-issuer` kind in your Ingress definition:

```
Annotations:                 certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-dns
```

But the object you have defined is a `Certificate` kind:

```
Name:         site-cloud-tls
Namespace:    cs
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Certificate
```

That is why it is not being applied to the Ingress. What you need is to create an [Issuer](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/issuer/) resource in Kubernetes to handle the certificate. Here you can find an example of a basic [ACME](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/#solving-challenges) `ClusterIssuer` manifest file:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    # You must replace this email address with your own.
    # Let's Encrypt will use this to contact you about expiring
    # certificates, and issues related to your account.
    email: user@example.com
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # Secret resource that will be used to store the account's private key.
      name: example-issuer-account-key
    # Add a single challenge solver, HTTP01 using nginx
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```